# Injecting $http service into $http interceptor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, service-locator

I have the following interceptor:

```
var interceptor = ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
     //...
}];
```

This generates a **circular dependency**, because `$http` will depend on this interceptor, and this interceptor will depend on `$http`.

I want to get the `$http` service because I intend to refresh some authorization tokens of the user if I get a **401 Unauthorized** response.

For this, I have to call my OAuth endpoint and retrieve the new tokens.

How can I inject this service into my interceptor?

I also tried the following alternative:

```
var interceptor = ['$injector', '$q', function ($injector, $q) {
     var $http = $injector.get('$http');
}]
```

But I'm getting the same error.

Is this possible?

I don't want to use the `jQuery` library and I want my application to be pure AngularJS, so `$.ajax(...)` answers are not useful to me.

Comment: Maybe you can fire off an event or call another service to do the work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even the second snippet causes cdep error because interceptor service will get instantiated and in the constructor you are trying to get `$http` in the process, which causes cdep error. You would need to get the http service (or any of your service that injects http) later, after interceptor service has been instantiated. You could easily get it from `$injector` on demand when you need it, example on a `reponseError`.

```
var interceptor = ['$injector', '$q',
    function($injector, $q) {
      return {

        responseError: function(rejection) {
          //Get it on demand or cache it to another variable once you get it. But you dont really need to do that you could get from the injector itself since it is not expensive as service is a singleton.
          var $http = $injector.get('$http');
          //Do something with $http
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score -1):

try wrapping your injector code with in anonymous function

```
  var interceptor = ['$injector', '$q', function ($injector, $q) {
          return function(){
                var $http = $injector.get('$http');
          }
  }];
```